# Avoiding Registering Taps for .25 seconds after a double tap in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

Right now I have it so that two taps zooms in on a view and one tap brings up a new view. The problem is that currently if the user triple taps, the new view will still show up after the zoom is complete. I want to disable registering taps for 0.25 seconds after the double-tap/zoom. What's the best way to do this? I already have a method that is fired off after it registers a zoom as complete, so I could throw it in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something as simple as setting `userInteractionEnabled` on the view to `NO` when starting the zoom and `YES` when finishing the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in UI design. if you are using an animation to do the zoom you can disable the tap recognizer in your method and turn it back on in your completion block.

yourTapRecognizer.enabled = NO;

yourTapRecognizer.enabled = YES;

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 simple ways, you can choose any of them:

1. Disable the gesture recognizer (`gestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;`)
2. Disable user interaction on the view (`view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`)
3. Disable event handling in the app (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]`)

To enable the interaction again, you can use

```
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t) (0.25 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    //enable recognizer, set user interaction to YES or call endIgnoringInteractionEvents
});
```

However, I would recommend you to tie the handler to some event, instead of blindly using some magic time (`0.25 secs`). If you alread have such method, good for you!